# is there any way to execute code before the observable emits any item? (for retrying purposes)

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, retrofit2

i want to retry an observable with its subscription. it all went good but now I'm trying to execute some code every time i retry this observable. any suggestions?

```
observableItem.retry(1).subscribeWith(subscriber);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question,? Title and question both says different things.

Comment: i mean i want some code to run before emitting anything from the observable. in my case i wanted this to happen when i call retry on it

Answer (score 2):

You need `doOnSubscribe` operator that works when observable is subscribed(before observable emit any item).

```
...
observableItem
        .doOnSubscribe(subscriber1 -> {
            // Do whatever you want to de before retry.
        })
        .retry(1)
        .subscribeWith(subscriber)
...
```

Note: i have not tested it. Please test it and let me know.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Sami-Ikhleaf did it help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `retryWhen` instead of `retry`.

```
observableItem
  .retryWhen(attempts -> {
     return attemps.flatMap(error -> {
       // TODO: Do what you want here...

       // If you return an Observable with an `onNext` event => retry
       // else if you return an Observable with an error => no retry
       return Observable.just(new Object());
     })
  })
  .subscribeWith(subscriber);
```